# How to sort a list of object type

Tags: java, list, collections, comparator

Player class has been defined earlier. I want to sort a List of objects of type Player according to a particular attribute. However I am getting the the error : ')' expected for the following statement

```
Comparator <Player> compareBydefensiveDuel= (Player p1, Player p2)->(p1.getD().compareTo(p2.getD()));
```

I have also tried with the following statements:

```
Collections.sort(PlayerList,Comparator.comparing(Player ::getD());
PlayerList.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Player::getD()));
```

In all these cases it is asking for the ')' after Player. How to resolve this?

Comment: `Collections.sort(PlayerList,Comparator.comparing(Player::getD));`

Comment: What is return type of `getD()`? If `Double`, then your code should work fine. If `double`, then you need this instead: `(Player p1, Player p2) -> Double.compare(p1.getD(), p2.getD())`

Comment: *FYI:* As shown in [comment by michalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586167/how-to-sort-a-list-of-object-type#comment103486028_58586167), when you *call* a method, syntax is `xxx.method()`. When you build a *method reference*, syntax is `xxx::method`, without the `()`

Comment: The first code example surely doesn’t produce the error you describe. If `getD()` returns the primitive type `double`, you’ll get something like “double cannot be dereferenced”.

Answer (score 1):

With java 8 method reference, you must not use parentheses

Instead of Player::getD()
Use Player::getD

```
Collections.sort(PlayerList,Comparator.comparing(Player::getD));
```